# Facebook best auth flow with Accounts.framework

Tags: ios, facebook

I've read tons of information about `ACAccounts.framework` and successfully integrated it in my application.

To be honest all that tutorials don't have good error flow and what to do next.

My following auth works fine:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey : kPSFacebookKey,
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceEveryone};

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                          options:options
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted) {
            NSArray *accounts = [_currentUser.accountStore
                                 accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            _currentUser.facebook = [accounts firstObject];                
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                authSuccess(); 
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                authFailure(error);
                // Display UIAlertView to make user go to settings and add account?! WHAT?
            });
        }
    }];
```

If user has account in settings and I rely on it and consider that user is logged in.

This really works as expected, but just if granted, just if user has account in `settings`.
Otherwise I display alert to make user go to `settings` and add account. I don't want like that!

So, desired flow is:

- if user has account in `settings` fetch it via `ACAccountStore` WORKS
- if user doesn't have account in `settings` -> go to `facebook` app?
- if user doesn't have `facebook` app -> go to `safari` `facebook` login form -> login then go back to application

I believe `Foursquare` has such flow.

So my main questions are:

- How I can achieve such flow (see above)
- Do I need for that `Facebook iOS SDK`
- Can I merge then credentials from `Facebook` session and add it to `ACAccountStore` manually?

thanks

Comment: You'd need the Facebook SDK for that. It takes care of what workflows to use to authenticate (ACAccountStore, Safari, or Facebook app), and gives you an access token in return.

Comment: I don't want to FBDialog to be displayed etc... Facebook login tutorials are pretty confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across this `gist`:

https://gist.github.com/rsms/4726728

Following expectations are met:

- if user has account in `settings` fetch it via `ACAccountStore`
- if user doesn't have account in `settings` -> go to facebook app
- if user doesn't have `Facebook` app -> go to `safari` `Facebook` login form -> enter credentials -> automatically back to application

What is really cool is that I don't have to manually fetch `ACAccountStore` (accounts in iOS system), Facebook SDK does it for me, and I'm just rely on Facebook session (isOpen).

One issue still were is that session disappears after restarting application, and this was solved by adding:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:NO
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {}];
```